# Using a common folder in multiple repos on Github

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I've been looking for an answer for a long time but I suppose it's time to ask someone who knows how to use Github :)

I'd like to have a common folder for multiple repos. What I mean with common folder is, whenever I make changes on a specific folder and sync, same folder should be updated in all repos.

Real world example may clarify the situation. I'm developing four different Wordpress themes and they share same folder, "framework". Either I need a master framework folder that pushes updates to all repos or a master repo that pushes updates to all repos.

Mine is simple logic but I believe this should be one of basic features of Github although I wasn't able to find out for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "common" repository, then add it as a submodule to your other repositories.  Then add a post-commit hook to update the submodule across your repos when you update the "common" repo.  AFAIK, this is the only way to "share" across repositories.

Great, in depth examples here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Edit:
Lots of info on hooks: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Great! Apparently it's going to be lots of readings on Submodule. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Finally I managed to separate framework folder as a repo and use it as submodule, works as expected. However, although cloning a repo allows to get submodules and makes easier to work with, downloading as zip excludes submodule content and it makes impossible to distribute project. Only way looks like using git-archive-all script but it requires to clone project first. What is the proper way to archive and export repo with submodules?